# show only the labels in x coordinate that correspond to facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                 b=c("x1","x2","y1","y2","w1","w2"), 
                 c=runif(6), 
                 d=c(1,1,2,2,3,3))
ggplot(aes(x=b, y=c), data=df) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid(~d)
```

I'm trying to plot the labels in `b` within each corresponding facet, so only `x1` and `x2` in facet 1, `y1` and `y2` in facet 2 etc. However with the code above the other labels not belonging to the facet are also showing up

Comment: You can try adding `scales = "free_x"` inside `facet_grid(...)`.

Comment: @Z.Lin, thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.